# Has anyone gotten Padrino to work with Sprockets and Compass?

Tags: ruby, rack, sprockets, padrino

I'm on Padrino 0.10.7 and I haven't been able to get Sprockets to recognize Compass in the load path.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only question on SO I've found on this topic.

Got this working with the following:

- [padrino-pipeline](https://github.com/Ortuna/padrino-pipeline) gem - going down the Sprockets route

Somewhere (I used my app.rb file) you will need the following:

```
Sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/compass/stylesheets"
Sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets"
```

Not sure if there is a simpler way. Feels like there should be. Also, any neat ways of getting image-url() sass method working?

**EDIT**: There is a way to get image-url working - if you thought the above was messy, add this to your app.rb too...

```
assets.context_class.class_eval do
  def settings
    YourAppName::App.settings
  end

  include Padrino::Helpers::AssetTagHelpers
end
```

(where YourAppName is the name of the module that describes your application, at the top of app.rb)